# List<Type> converted to IEnumerable<Interface> and then to List<Interface> is null

Tags: c#, linq, interface, casting

forgive me if the title is unclear but I couldn't find another way to describe what I encountered.
I ran into a problem when writing code that is analogous to the following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public interface IInterfaceReadOnly
{
    int Value {get;}
}

public interface IInterface : IInterfaceReadOnly
{
    new int Value{get; set;}
}

public class Implementation : IInterface {
    public int Value{get; set;}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Implementation> implementations = new List<Implementation>();
        IEnumerable<IInterfaceReadOnly> generic = implementations;

        List<IInterfaceReadOnly> listOfGeneric1 = generic as List<IInterfaceReadOnly>;
        List<IInterfaceReadOnly> listOfGeneric2 = generic.ToList();

        // this prints "is null", listOfGeneric1 is null
        if (listOfGeneric1 == null) Console.WriteLine("Is null");
        else Console.WriteLine("Not null");

        // this prints "not null", listOfGeneric2 is converted successfully
        if (listOfGeneric2 == null) Console.WriteLine("Is null");
        else Console.WriteLine("Not null");
    }
}
```

As written in the comments, the first conversion with the "as" operator returns null, meaning that the casting failed, on the other hand, casting with ToList() works just fine.
Thanks in advance for any clarifications.

Comment: Maybe I'm just tired at the end of a long day. But I'm really not sure what you are trying to do here. What exactly is your question?

Comment: `List<T>` is invariant so a `List<Implementation>` is not a `List<IInterfaceReadonly>`.

Comment: They are different things though. If you make an `Implementation2: IInterface` you can't add that to your `implementations` but you should be able to add it to your `listOfGeneric1` proving they're not the same thing, which is also the reason why you can't cast it (so the cast results in `null`). Look up Covariance and contravariance if you would like to learn more.

Comment: This is not the correct way to convert an IEnumerable to a List: `List<IInterfaceReadOnly> listOfGeneric1 = generic as List<IInterfaceReadOnly>;`.  This IS the correct way to convert an IEnumerable to a List: `List<IInterfaceReadOnly> listOfGeneric2 = generic.ToList();`. As you see in your `Console.WriteLine's`, the first failed, the second worked.  Use the one that works!  (This is why I'm confused as to what you are actually asking.)

Comment: "casting" using the `ToList()` method (which isn't actually casting) works because the `IEnumerable<T>` type you're starting with has the element type you want (i.e. `IInterfaceReadOnly`). The implicit type conversion from `List<Implementation>` works because `List<Implementation>` implements `IEnumerable<Implementation>`, and being covariant, the `IEnumerable<Implementation>` type can be implicitly converted to `IEnumerable<IInterfaceReadOnly>`. But a) that conversion can only widen the type parameter (i.e. go from more derived to less derived) and b) it works only with covariant interfaces.

Comment: Generic type variance is supported only for interfaces, not classes, and even if it were supported for classes (like `List<T>`), the `List<T>` class itself would not be covariant, because values of `T` are both returned by and passed to the object (for variance to work, only one or the other can be true). See marked duplicate, and the hundreds of other questions relating to generic type variance, for more details.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for the answer, didn't think this had anything to do with variance at all, hence this duplicate question. Thanks for the explaination!

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I asked this question because it wasn't clear to me why that behaviour was occuring, now I know it.